# Installing Sharepoint Designer 2013 on Windows 10 with Office 2016 and Visio 2013 -stuck, not moving

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I a trying to install SD 2013 on Windows 10 with Office 2016 and Visio 2013
I am installing x86 (32bit) and it is stuck in this screen
The above Office components are x32 so I am OK in that respect
I am using elevated rights to install, not sure if it matters (ie I am not admin on my machine)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue that already reported at [SharePoint Designer will not install](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-designer-will-not-install/3c485074-6059-45d3-a55b-46e089fa02de)

**Solution**

1. Login to your PC with an local admin account.
2. Open Task Scheduler.
3. Locate the Task Scheduler `Library\Microsoft\Office`
4. Delete every task if exists > Right Click on the `Office folder` > Delete it.
5. Start to install the SharePoint Designer that should be installed properly

Comment: Yes I came across that article too. I  was able to delete that folder from my account Not sure if it would be different from the admin account. Deleting from my account and trying to install did not work. I will ask the help desk guys tomorrow ..thank you

Comment: Welcome, please don't forget to feedback us with accepting and upvoting the answer if it worked, or provide the solution that worked with you to be valuable for all coming users Thanks! :)